# Web development jQuery percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have two divs; one div has the old price and the other div has the new price. I want to make the second div take the string inside the first div, convert it into a number, take 20% off of it then replace the second div with that number.

I have managed to produce some code myself, however I can only get it to work once. I want it work each time, even if the div has the same class but a different value.

```
<div>£<span class="old"><s>599</s></span></div>First Div
<div>£<span class="new">599</span></div> Second Div

var $x = $(".old").text();
var iNum = parseInt($x);
var $y = 0.20;
var result = Math.round(iNum * $y);
var $newPrice = $(".new").text($x - result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the wierd single quotes you are mixing your variables. Try this:

```
var $x = $(".old").text();
var iNum = parseInt($x);
var $y = 0.20;
var result = Math.round(iNum * $y);
$(".new").text(iNum - result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: How would I apply this logic to multiple divs with the same class(these exact classes), so that when I can change the price in the ".old" it will automatically update the ".new" with the changed price?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your code in a `function`.  Here's a working example, where every time you run it, it changes the "old" value (just to show that it can be run multiple times).

```js
function getPercent() {
  var $x = $(".old").text();
  var iNum = parseInt($x);
  var $y = 0.20;
  var result = Math.round(iNum * $y);
  var $newPrice = $(".new").text($x - result);
  $(".old").text(parseInt($(".old").text()) - 10);
}

document.getElementById('runBtn').addEventListener('click', getPercent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>£<span class="old"><s>599</s></span></div>First Div
<div>£<span class="new">599</span></div> Second Div

<br /><br />

<button id="runBtn">Run</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!  For the help